# Hammer.js: do some logic while swiping

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I am working with hammer.js and now I want to change the width of an element by using the touch x-axis distance:

```
var swipeEvent = Hammer(element).on( 'touch' , function (event) {
        console.log("x: " + event.gesture.startEvent.touches[0].deltaX);

        var curWidth = $('#box-id').css('width');
        console.log("swipe!!    :" + curWidth);
        $('#box-id').css('width', curWidth + curWidth);
    }   
  );
```

Now of cource the problem is the the code is only execute once at the event. How do I run some logic always changing the width while the touch has not ended? is this possible with hammer.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for the `drag` event, which gets fired continuously as you drag your finger, instead of `touch`:

https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started#gesture-events